# Restrict listing a "root" directory in ProFTPD

Tags: ftp

I have an FTP server set up where, off the root, there is a file structure laid out by city.  Underneath each city's folder are more folders organized by project.  I would like to be able to restrict my guest users (using a specific login/password) in such a way that they are unable to view the folders under the city name, but instead have be brought directly to them via an FTP link.

Example:

/
--City1
----Project1
----Project2
----Project3
--City2
----Project4
--City3
----Project5

link:  ftp://ftp.company.com/City2/Project4

Answer (score 0):

To do this, when you create the user you set their home directory to be for example `/City2/Project4`. You also configure the proftpd DefaultRoot directive in `proftpd.conf` to lock the user to their home directory.

```
DefaultRoot ~
```

Comment: Unfortunately, we use one guest account for all users.  I can't restrict to a specific project directory without creating hundreds of accounts that may only be used one time.

Comment: I don't think you can do that.

Comment: OK.  Thank you.  I'll see how I can change my environment

Answer (score 0):

The question states "specific login/passwords", but then a reply states "we use one guest account". It can be done using one guest account and proftpd virtual users using AuthUserFiles and Limit configurations. Many examples for this in the proftpd manual, see "Configuring Limits" and "Using AuthUserFiles".